# Google script trigger is lost on copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a google spreadsheet with an embedded script.  I have set the trigger to fire on change and everything is working as expected.  When I make a copy of the script The trigger is lost and needs to be reset.  I am deploying this a s a spreadsheet for my company and I need to have others make a copy and distribute each month with a different name.  Is there any way to prevent the trigger from being lost on each copy.  I have looked around but I have not found an answer as of yet.  I tried to place a function called **onChange(e)** but it did not fire without a trigger being set pointing at it.  Thank you to all who may be able to make suggestions.

Comment: Write code that checks for the existence of the trigger every time the code runs, and adds the trigger if it's not there.  Another option is to publish an Add-on privately, or to a Google Group and have people install the Add-on.  The Add-on option may have some features that you might like better than distributing the spreadsheet.  For one thing, users have no access to the code in the Add-on.

Comment: those special triggers (onChange onOpen onEdit) do get copied. what you are likely missing is  permission (fro those making the copies) to run the script. provide a menu item. apps script will ask for permissions when the user clicks the menu item

Answer (score 2):

In apps script you can setup a trigger onEdit to a specific function but if you have a function onEdit() in your script it will be fired automatically.

For your point on the copy, just after the copy the trigger onEdit() can't run because you must have to validate authorization to let script run on your account.

If you validate authorization and have a onEdit() function on your script it will be fired after validation.

You have to validate authorization for each script linked to a spreadsheet not possible to overcome that even if the script is the same in multiple spreadsheet.

It is the behavior of apps script in a spreadsheet, no way to overcome.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helps me much! This should be accept answer.